# Vuetify: Dynamically set breakpoint?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a slider that i want to use to set the breakpoints on a grid of flex boxes. Adjusting the grid xs1 thru xs12 based on current value the 'columns' data point. I've tried v-bind, that does not work. How would I acheive this?

the slider:

```
<v-slider
  v-model="columns"
  :label="`Columns : ${columns}`"
  max="12"
  ticks
  ></v-slider>
```

the flexes:

```
<v-flex 
  v-for="(val, index) in numberOfRecords" 
  :key="index" 
  v-bind="`xs${columns}`">
```

the data:

```
data: () => ({
  numberOfRecords: 40,
  columns: 6,
}),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [pass an object to `v-bind`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-the-Properties-of-an-Object), which will bind the value of the object to an attribute with the same name as the key:

```
v-bind="{[`xs${columns}`]: true}"
```